# LINQ - how to create a list of distinct items

Tags: c#, linq

How can I make a LINQ query that would return a new list of distinct Operators from the Workpacks table (DB is not normalized). I got this query, but I don't know how to use DISTINCT properly, so that SQL server doesn't return duplicate values

```
Instance.CriteriaOperatorList = 
    (from v in context.Workpacks
     select new FilterCriteriaItem()
     {
         GUID = Guid.NewGuid(),
         Name = v.Operator,
     }).ToList();
```

Comment: It depends on what collection you want to `distinct` on, Workpacks?  Or the output of your `select`?

Comment: Is this LINQ to Entities?

Comment: What part is supposed to be distinct? The objects you're returning will all be unique since they have different GUIDs...

Comment: Sorry ... distinct Operators from the Workpacks table - DB is not normalized, and Operator names are stored in the Workpacks table, not unique

Comment: I like using  GroupBy with first which is equivalent to Distinct : nstance.CriteriaOperatorList = context.Workpacks.Select(v => new FilterCriteriaItem() {
                                                 GUID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                                                 Name = v.Operator
            }).GroupBy(x => new { GUID = x.GUID, Name = x.Name }).Select(x => x.First()).ToList<FilterCriteriaItem>();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get the distinct `Operator`s from the `Workpack`, then get those. The easiest way to do that is to not use the SQL LINQ syntax.

```
Instance.CriteriaOperatorList = context.Workpacks
                                       // Only request the Operator names
                                       .Select(w => w.Operator)
                                       // But just request the distinct names
                                       .Distinct()
                                       // Then select into your DTO.
                                       .Select(o => new FilterCriteriaItem
                                       {
                                           GUID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                                           Name = o // o is the Operator from Workpack
                                       })
                                       .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use .Distinct() before .To list().

Comment: OP wants distinct `Operator` before createing the new `FilterCriteriaItem`